# Stop SQL stored procedure from executing twice

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, model-view-controller

I have an issue with stored procedure that is executing twice from one call only. Here is how I call it:

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnection(read_intent: false)))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("prc.name", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test", object.test);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

and my stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [prc.name]
@test int,
as
begin try
set nocount on
    update tbl.name set 
        value_count = (value_count + 1),
        _test = @test
end try
```

The problem is when I check the value_count and it is not increased by 1, but by 2 from calling the procedure once. I throw an exception write after the procedure is executed to ensure that I don't call it from somewhere else. Help for this, because I looked the whole process from start to the end 20 times and I don't have a clue for the issue.

Comment: Is it possible that another application is calling the same Stored Procedure? FYI You don't need to explicitly call `Close` on your connection here, `using` takes care of that for you.

Comment: Do your procedure/table names actually have `.`s in them? Is that your *actual* procedure?

Comment: @James It is not possible to be called from somewhere else, I search for every possible call to it. I agree for the Close, but it is not the point here, it is just a take a precaution

Comment: @VladimirAbazarov I mean from *another* application, not in your application. If it's definitely not being called twice from your application then clearly it's being called externally or it's a problem with the SP itself (which looks OK). Also, it's an unnecessary precaution because `using` is pretty much guaranteed to clean up the connection.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever these are not the real names and procedure. The procedure is a lot complicated, I've just posted the logic here.

Comment: My suspicion would be that the stored procedure is only being called once but the "complicated logic" is actually doing more than you think it is (and thus producing the unexpected result(s) that you're currently characterizing as the stored procedure being called twice)

Comment: Is it possible you have a update trigger that's also incrementing the value?

Comment: @James I am gonna view and the others applications too, thanks for the advice. Gonna PM you when I check.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke it is not possible, I don't have any other ways to execute query to SQL, only from procedures that I pass objects.

Comment: I mean, does your database table have a trigger

Comment: Did you try to use sql server profiler to be sure your stored procedure is not being called twice ?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke no the table don't have trigger

Comment: @NicoD I execute the procedure with dummy data and it log the +1 as it should be, the problem is in the inner layers in MVC, I have just found the problem, I will post it in a minute here

Comment: After some hours on that issue I finally found the problem. The problem was that I started from the middle to the end(Controller to Procedure and DB). The issue was in the View, where I was having ViewData tag that was expecting Data to be send from the Controller, but I've never send it... This makes the page to load for the first time, call the procedure and etc, and after that reloading again in 1-2 seconds interval and executing it again. NOTE: For all people who may have that Issue, make sure you have covered the whole process and look for big things like this. 10x everyone for the help.